# Почему IDEA не видит generated-sources файл?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

В папке `Target` имеются сгенерированные файлы. Файлы, которые сгенерированы в фолдере для тестов IDEA я могу импортировать, а файлы из папки generated-sources нет. Фолдеры  промаркированы. [image: скрин]

Comment: так то в таргете класс файлы лежат, почему у Вас туда сгенерированные файлы попали?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не видит, потому что расположение исходников четко определено структурой проекта и по-моему изменить его нельзя штатными способами. Используйте gradle он имеет такие возможности.

Не штатно можно попробовать использовать дополнительные плагины, например,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java/</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Оставьте в import что-то наподобие

```
import com.google.openrtb.OpenRtb;
```

Остальное пусть сделает автоимпорт